# Autofill shipping address using email by ajax but after click on submit button showing error this is a required filled

Tags: magento2

I have applied ajax on fill email address. After enter email address ajax is running and taking address and fill like below

> $('input[name="firstname"]').val(obj.addressData['firstname'])

But after click on submit button it is showing error message "This is a required field."

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple reference:

// this is the id of the form

```
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: actionUrl,
        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
          alert(data); // show response from the php script.
        }
    });
    
});
```